# Creation of database installer script like DRUPAL

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I have two ways to create structure of tables in database

1. Import a sql file in database using UI or shell.
2. create a php database  installer script like drupal.

I want to know about which will be the good way to create database structure or is there any other way apart from above.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your programming question please. This is not a discussion board.

Comment: I want to have some information about database installation script

Comment: I don not want to have discussion,I just want to know that if  I create a database installation script so that user just click on install.php and database gets install on server. Is this a good approach or I should use .sql files using mysqldump

Comment: that is still not a programming question IMHO (you don't show and you didn't make any code). This website is to help you with coding problem if you ask a good question.

Comment: Sorry for that it is not a programming question but it is really Important for me to get this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends how are you going to use it, but if you are creating a *drupal* type CMS, then creating an automatic table structure is most likely the best approach.

Comment: If I have altered some tables and then if I migrate my database server, I have to manually update my code in automated script for table creation don't you feel it is a drawback for automatic table structure script